# Quickblox, send push notification via REST API

Tags: quickblox

When trying to send a push notification:

```
{'event[environment]': 'development', 'event[notification_type]': 'push', 'event[message]': u'payload=VGhpcyBpcyBhIHB1c2ggbm90aWZpY2F0aW9uIEFQSSBUZXN0', 'event[user][ids]': 'xxx', 'token': xxx'}
```

I get following result from the API.

```
{"code":null,"message":"invalid byte sequence in UTF-8"}
```

The Payload is a base64 encoded string, so it should work properly. Anyone an idea what's wrong here?

thanks,
phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your message is not in the correct format:

Did you encode a JSON Object like the following one as Base64 ?

```
"aps": { "alert": "Some text", "badge": 1, "sound": "default" }
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, the actual json should look like this: {"aps":{"alert":"Some text","badge":1,"sound":"default"}}

Comment: The funny thing is that while the notification is now sent, the api still returns the error message.

Comment: Hi Igor, the call did not cause an error, just replied with:
{"code":null,"message":"invalid byte sequence in UTF-8"}